# Solaris 8 available for download?

Tags: solaris, sunos

A customer of mine is still using Solaris 8, now I have a product which requires testing against this OS, however looking at Oracle, they merely provide 10 and 11. Is it possible to find Solaris 8 for download (x86) still? Or is it a lost cause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solaris 8 was last shipped on February 16, 2007. You can only get patches for it until end of march 2012 after which it will reach its end of service life.

Comment: Alright, so not even a test/development version is available anywhere?

Comment: Mmm, thanks. Now I shall go sailing into a bay or something.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a valid developer account and/or maintenance agreement with Oracle.  I do not believe those are free.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris 8 was only released for the SPARC architecture. Your best bet is to contact Oracle and see if they will sell you any CDs. You should be able to pick up a SPARC machine capable of running Solaris 8 on the second user market. For software package etc there is always sunfreeware.com.

Comment: Solaris 8 was definitely released for both SPARC and x86. From Solaris 2.2 onward, the source code was unified and both SPARC and x86 architecture were supported and released. Only Solaris 9 was released a little later for x86 than SPARC but that was the only incident.

Comment: Thanks for educating me. I only used SPARCs till 10 came out. I do recall an early version of 2.x for x86 but (obviously incorrectly) though that it was dropped early on.

Comment: @jlliagre: I don't suppose you can help with [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/330943/sun-tool-less-slide-rails-removal-for-x4150) can you ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I have no experience with these.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running their existing binaries on Solaris 10? ideally it should run as Solaris provides "Binary Gurantee" which means binaries compiled for old version of OS should run on new version os OS without a recompiling.

Comment: sorry forgot this is a very old  question.

Comment: Always good for future reference. However, this was not a possibility due to specific configurations and such. Long story, however, I did end up finding a working copy of Solaris 8 in a bay with by sailing boat...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumping here, since this page is one of the top results in Google, this is a link to acquire sunos 5.8 / Solaris 8
http://facilier.winworldpc.com/Abandonware%20Operating%20Systems/Misc/Sun%20Solaris%208%20x86.7z

Answer (score 0):

Download Solaris 8  for x86
http://old-dos.ru/index.php?page=files&mode=files&do=show&id=5152

[SPARC] Sun Solaris 8 2/04 (HW4)

```
CD:
sol-8-hw4-install-sparc.iso -- Solaris 8 2/04 Installation (SPARC Platform Edition) CD

sol-8-hw4-lang-sparc.iso -- Solaris 8 Languages (SPARC Platform Edition) CD

sol-8-hw4-sparc-v1.iso -- Solaris 8 2/04 Software (SPARC Platform Edition) CD 1 of 2

sol-8-hw4-sparc-v2.iso -- Solaris 8 2/04 Software (SPARC Platform Edition) CD 2 of 2

sol-8-hw4-supp.iso -- Solaris 8 2/04 Software Supplement CD

DVD: SOL_8_204_SPARC.iso -- Solaris 8 2/04 Operating Environment DVD, содержит материалы:
Solaris 8 2/04 Installation (SPARC Platform Edition) CD

Solaris 8 2/04 Software (SPARC Platform Edition) CDs (1 of 2 and 2 of 2)

Solaris 8 Languages (SPARC Platform Edition) CD

Solaris 8 2/04 Documentation CDs

8_Recommended.zip -- Solaris 8 SPARC Recommended Patch Cluster (Apr/24/09)

J2SE_Solaris_8_Recommended.zip -- J2SE Solaris 8 SPARC Recommended Patch Cluster (Mar/11/09)

java_es_2_3_4_required_comp_patches_solaris8-sparc.zip -- Java ES 2,3,4 Component Patch Solaris 8 SPARC (Mar/19/09)
```

http://doutdess.org/sun-solaris-8-2-torrent-18015

Answer (score 0):

Solaris 8 2/02 x86 appears obtainable from WinWorld (https://winworldpc.com/product/sun-solaris/8).

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of reasons to not use Solaris-8 (too old for security updates for one). However, if you have purchased an ULTRA_5 or Sunblade-150 at a garage sale, or are running a museum, then original CDROMs can be purchased on eBay for $50. They can also be downloaded from https://archive.org ("I believe" these were made "public domain" by Sun Microsystems before the takeover by Oracle). Beware that SPARC usually means 32-bit CPUs while UltraSPARC means 64-bit CPUs.